# How do I filter data from database arrays using Search bar

Tags: xcode, search, filter

Im using the search bar to filter data from the database and will populate the tableView. Im getting an error on the isSearching part.

```
Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'contains'
```

Heres the code.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredColorRequests = colors.filter{$0.contains(searchBar.text!)}
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

How

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly want to search for a specific `String` property for example a `name`.

And rather than getting the search string form the bar use the `searchText` parameter which is already non-optional.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredColorRequests = colors.filter{(($0.value as! [String:Any])["name"] as! String).contains(searchText)}
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Hi @vadian. when i try to type something it doesnt show anything. I've already updated the cellForRowAt

Comment: `name` is just a placeholder. I have no idea what the snapshot contains.

Comment: its working @vadian. thanks! i have one more question. what code do you use to filter the distance from the current user. Like i want to show on the list the nearest person to the furthest. i have im my snapshot the userA Longitude and latitude.

Comment: Use the API of `CoreLocation`. It’s easy to create `CLLocation` objects from lat/long and calculate the distance between two locations.

Comment: im so amazed! the searchBar is now working @vadian do you mind helping me with this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799390/how-to-make-a-expandable-side-menu-tableview-list

Comment: how do i make this case insensitive?

Comment: Replace `.contains(searchText)` with `.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil`