# How to put a checkmark after search

Tags: swift, search, tableview, checkmark

Im trying to put checkmarks after doing a search. I've seen some answers here but it doesn't work for me. Ive tried some of the answers but it will only make an error.

Here's the code that I wrote.

```
struct finalCheckednames { var name: String; var checkMark: Bool}

class ShowBroadcastNamesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

var nameslist = ["Mark","Chris", "James", "Sandra"]
var myIndex = 0
var nameArray = String()
var filteredData = [String]()
var isSearching = false
var selectedNamesToBroadcast = [String]()
var selectedNamesIndex:Int? = nil
var checkmarks = [Int : Bool]()
var hasChecked = Bool()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? broadcastNamesTableViewCell {

        let text: String!

        if isSearching {
            text = filteredData[indexPath.row]

        } else {
            text = nameslist[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.configureCell(text: text)

        if checkmarks[indexPath.row] != nil {
            cell.accessoryType = checkmarks[indexPath.row]! ? .checkmark : .none
        } else {
            checkmarks[indexPath.row] = false
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

        return cell

    } else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if isSearching {
            selectedNamesIndex = filteredData[indexPath.row] // im also getting an error here

        } else {

    selectedNamesIndex = indexPath.row
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if let index = selectedNamesIndex {
        if (cell?.accessoryType == .checkmark) {
            cell!.accessoryType = .none
            checkmarks[indexPath.row] = false
            hasChecked = false

            let indexPathTapped = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
            let name = nameslist[(indexPathTapped!.row)]
            print(name, hasChecked)
            if let index = selectedNamesToBroadcast.index(of: name) {
                selectedNamesToBroadcast.remove(at: index)
            }

        } else {
            cell!.accessoryType = .checkmark
            checkmarks[indexPath.row] = true
            hasChecked = true

            let indexPathTapped = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
            let name = nameslist[(indexPathTapped!.row)]
            print(name, hasChecked)
            selectedNamesToBroadcast.append(name)

            let selectedNamesToBroadcast = name

            finalCheckednames(name: name, checkMark: hasChecked)
            print(finalCheckednames.self, "XXXX")
        }
    }

}

 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredData = namelist.filter{$0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
        tableView.reloadData()
```

I was hoping for the checkmarks to stay after searching. So atleast i can save all the checkmarked items somewhere.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you should create a struct so that the string and checkmark are tied together, `struct Name { var name: String; var checkMark: Bool}`, and then use that struct in your arrays

Comment: does that mean i should put an `Int` in the struct too? because im also using the `Int` in  `var checkmarks = [Int : Bool]()`

Comment: I don't think so if the Int is supposed to represent an index or similar.

Comment: I updated the code(posted on top) and tried to print `finalCheckednames`, it just printed finalCheckednames XXXX. apologies, im new to this.

Comment: You are supposed to use the struct in your arrays instead of String,  nameslist and filteredData

Comment: Does that mean i need to replace `filteredData = namelist.filter{$0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}` in `func searchBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very, very, very complicated. The most efficient way to accomplish your request is to use the `isChecked` information in the struct, nothing else, no extra arrays, dictionaries, properties.

Give the struct and the Bool a more meaningful name.

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    var isChecked: Bool
}
```

In the controller name the data source array `people` and the filter array `filteredPeople`. Further you need only `isSearching`, delete all other properties

```
class ShowBroadcastNamesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var people = [Person(name: "Mark", isChecked: false),
                  Person(name: "Chris", isChecked: false),
                  Person(name: "James", isChecked: false),
                  Person(name: "Sandra", isChecked: false)]

    var filteredPeople = [Person]()
    var isSearching = false
```

```
var myIndex = 0
var nameArray = String()
var filteredData = [String]()
var selectedNamesToBroadcast = [String]()
var selectedNamesIndex:Int? = nil
var checkmarks = [Int : Bool]()
var hasChecked = Bool()
```

In `cellForRow` force unwrap the custom cell and name it uppercased (good practice). Pass the `name` to `configureCell` and set the accessory view depending on the value of `isChecked`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BroadcastNamesTableViewCell

    let person = isSearching ? filteredPeople[indexPath.row] : people[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(text: person.name)
    cell.accessoryType = person.isChecked ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

In `didSelectRow` toggle `isChecked` (and update also the `people` array if necessary) and reload the row, that's all

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if isSearching {
        filteredPeople[indexPath.row].isChecked.toggle()
        let index = people.firstIndex{$0.name == filteredPeople[indexPath.row].name}!
        people[index].isChecked.toggle() 
    } else {
        people[indexPath.row].isChecked.toggle()
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

In `textDidChange` search for the name

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        isSearching = false
        filteredPeople.removeAll()
        view.endEditing(true)
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredPeople = people.filter{$0.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57800914/how-do-i-filter-data-from-database-arrays-using-search-bar/57801132#57801132) I already suggested a more efficient version of `textDidChange`, please consider to follow the advices.

To get the checked people just write

```
let checkedPeople = people.filter{$0.isChecked}
```

Comment: thank you for all of your help @vadian. its working. But when i search for a name and i checkmark it, it works, but when I stop searching and goes back to the original list the check mark of the searched name is gone.

Comment: Make the `struct` a `class` to get reference semantics. I updated the answer.

Comment: sad to say, its still the same. the checkmark disappears after search

Comment: OK, revert the changes and keep `Person` a struct. I changed `didSelectAt` to update the main array. Replace the method. Note: If there are two or more people with the same name you need another property to distinguish the items.

Comment: Thank you so much. its working now. Just have a question how come when i print `checkedPeople` it prints `Nameofproject.Person(name: "Mark", isChecked: true)` Database doesnt accept this format. I just need the String `Mark` in the database

Comment: Please read the code and try to understand it. You get the name with the `.name` property like in `cellForRow`, `didSelect` or `textDidChange`.

Comment: Thanks @vidian for your help

Comment: i need the `.name` which is also filtered by `isChecked`

Comment: If you want an array of names rather than an array of `Person` `map` the array: `let checkedNames = people.filter{$0.isChecked}.map{$0.name}`

Comment: have you encounter this before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935114/placing-map-annotation-of-specific-database-value

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Firebase